# IQKeyboardManager is not working in Xcode 9 , next , prev & done buttons are not on Keyboard toolbar

Tags: keyboard, toolbar, xcode9, iqkeyboardmanager

IQKeyboardmanager toolbar works fine if i use Xcode8, but when i use Xcode 9 there is no next , prev & done buttons on Keyboard toolbar.Even other feature are not working in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
```